# Вывод условия согласно субдомена wordpress

Tags: wordpress, acf, wordpress-multisite

Добрый день может кто сталкивался

я сделал чтобы субдомены отображали тоже что отображается на основном сайте Wordpress
но мне нада добавить возможность что бы на субдоменах были свои телефоны адреса и прочее

использую ACF
кто подскажет может кто сталкивался

```
<?php if ( is_page( $page = '//subdomain.domain' ) ) : ?> 
    --тут вывести поле -- 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: это мультисайт?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего парсить HTTP_POST из серверного массива:

```php
$url_parts = explode( '.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

if ( count( $url_parts > 2 ) && 'yoursubdomain' === $url_parts[0] ) {
    // Do something...
}
```

`count( $url_parts > 2 )` проверяет, что у нас минимум 3 составляющих, это позволит отбросить основной домен.

Примечание: если планируете данное значение субдомена потом записывать в базу или выводить где-нибудь – тогда не забывайте, что это потенциально небезопасные данные и стоит прибегнуть к санитизации, например с помощью `esc_url_raw()` (спасибо @wp-punk за напоминание).